# python - beautifulsoup - removing a line of code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I started to learn the beautifulsoup. I am trying to remove from html script a line of code containing `</div>` .

The most examples in the documentation are presented for the whole tags (opening and closing part). 

Is it possible to modify just one part of a tag? 
For example:

```
</div>
<div >Hello</div>
<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>
```

**how to remove just the first line of the code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup's [`unwrap()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) to specify the invalid tag, which will only remove the extra tags that don't have a open/close counterpart, while retaining others:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

invalid_tags = ['</div>']

for tag in invalid_tags: 
    for match in soup.findAll(tag):
        match.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

result:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `invalid_tags = ['<\div>']` be `['</div>']`?

Comment: I don't know, but that works too and is probably the preferred convention, will update, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need do anything it will repaired automatically

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''</div> 
<div>World</div>
<div data-foo="value">foo!''' # also invalid, no closing

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

output

```
<div>World</div>
<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>
```

`unwrap()` is for removing not repairing tag.